# проблема с CPasswordHelper yii crypt

Tags: php, yii, yii2, валидация

При использовании `hashPassword($password,$cost=13)` постоянно возвращает "yii Internal error while generating hash."

Как я понял, не проходит условие

```
(function_exists('mb_strlen') ? mb_strlen($hash, '8bit') : strlen($hash)) < 32
```

из за того что `$hash=crypt($password,$salt);` 
всегда 13 символов, не пойму почему так.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-php -->
if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1) {
CPasswordHelper::hashPassword('rasmuslerdorf',$cost=13);
}

срабатывает исключение 
Internal error while generating hash.

Comment: Проверьте, доступен ли для PHP blowfish

Comment: if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1) {
  CPasswordHelper::hashPassword('rasmuslerdorf',$cost=13);
}

срабатывает исключение 
Internal error while generating hash.

Comment: Проблема была в версии PHP поменял 5.3.3-7+squeeze19 на PHP 5.3.29-1~dotdeb.0 и всё заработало